# Jmeter Java DSL - getting issues when using rpsThreadGroup

Tags: java, jmeter, dsl

When I use:
`threadGroup(50, Duration.ofSeconds(10)`

I see no issues it works fine, 100% of the time.

But when we use **rpsThreadGroup**, even though there are so much less throughput gets generated most of the time we see socket connection closed error:

`rpsThreadGroup() .maxThreads(50) .rampToAndHold(10, Duration.ofSeconds(5), Duration.ofSeconds(10)) .children( httpSampler("http://my.service") )`

Tried increasing the time for connectionTimeOut configuration, but it didn't solve the issue